# How to check whether for loop ends completely in python?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, break

This is a ceased for loop :

```
for i in [1,2,3]:
    print(i)
    if i==3:
        break
```

How can I check its difference with this :

```
for i in [1,2,3]:
    print(i)
```

This is an idea :

```
IsBroken=False
for i in [1,2,3]:
    print(i)
    if i==3:
        IsBroken=True
        break
if IsBroken==True:
    print("for loop was broken")
```

Comment: I think your idea is the best.  The else clause in python is only run when the for loop does not break. So detecting a break is probably best done as you suggest.  Go ahead and put that in your own answer if nothing better comes up.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

`for` loops can take an `else` block which can serve this purpose:

```
for i in [1,2,3]:
    print(i)
    if i==3:
        break
else:
    print("for loop was not broken")
```

Answer (score 12):

Python `for` loop has a else clause that is called iff the loop ends.

So, this would mean something in line

```
for i in [1,2,3]:
    print(i)
    if i==3:
        break
else:
    print("Loop Ended without break")
```

If instead you need to handle both the scenario, using exception for sequence control is also a viable alternative

```
try:
    for i in [1,2,3]:
        print(i)
        if i==3:
            raise StopIteration
except StopIteration:
    print ("Loop was broken")
else:
    print ("Loop was not broken")
```