# how to check when for loop is finished -python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

example:

```
i = 'string'
for x in i:
    print('hi this should print multiple times')
    #somthing that detects when for loop is finished
#or something that detects that here
```

its quite simple, all examples i found either didn't work/were really complex, and i'm just looking for something simple bc im sure theres a good way to do this and i just didn't find it.

links ive found but have not realy worked for me:

[this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38381850/how-to-check-whether-for-loop-ends-completely-in-python/38381893),
[this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50614701/python-for-loop-finish)

Comment: Not sure what you're asking about. According to the links you sent, I'm assuming you mean detect if the for loop executes completely (aka isn't interrupted)? if that's the case, please provide a complete example.

Comment: When the loop is finished the code after the loop will run. You can implement whatever logic you want to have *there*.

Comment: you have the ```else``` keyword. ```for x in y: pass else: print("Loops has finished")```

Comment: https://trinket.io/python/c21c686392 might help you

Comment: for x in i:
    print('hi this should print multiple times')
else:
  print("Loop ended!")

Comment: @JayMody i was just asking how to check when for loop is done, sorry for any confusion i may have caused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What are you trying to achieve? If you just want to run some code after the for loop is done, you can just put that piece of code after the for loop.

If you would like to check whether the loop completed "normally" (without encountering a break statement), you can use the for/else statement:

```
    for x in range(2, n):
        if n % x == 0:
            print( n, 'equals', x, '*', n/x)
            break
    else:
        # loop fell through without finding a factor
        print(n, 'is a prime number')
```

Source: https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/for_-_else.html